# select table row don't work, if element out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If the app starts, I need to select table row of the last element, that was used. 
The name of the last used element I save in plist. 
The code I used is:

```
id plist = [[PlistHandler alloc] init];// FIXME: Dont work with long list, if the element is out of view. 
    if ([tableData containsObject:[plist readDataForKey:@"selectedFile"]]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableData indexOfObject:[plist readDataForKey:@"selectedFile"]] inSection:0];
        [self.fileTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [self tableView:self.fileTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
```

The problem I found is: If the row is out of view ( table is big and the element if lower then view), I get some exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: selectedFile)'` Maybe someone know the better way to select a row or to work around.

**UPDATE:** 
I debuged a bit and now I know where the issue happen:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    id plist = [[PlistHandler alloc] init];
    [plist writeDataToKey:@"path" andData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, cellText]];
    [plist writeDataToKey:@"selectedFile" andData:cellText];
}
```

It's on the last line, because the cellText is nil, so maybe the index is wrong. 
Bit why it works with the elements, that are in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Cell is probably not initialized, because it has not be used. This is, because it is not on the screen.

The deeper problem is that you try to get data from the UI. The UI is for displaying data, not for storing and retrieving data. Retrieve the data from your model. Your application should know how to do this, because it knows how to set the cell.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html